# How to convert array object to one object in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have this script:

```
$i = 0
$Destination_Server = @()

foreach ($row in $Table | where { $_.cube_name -match "$CUBE" }) {
    $i++
    $Destination_Server += $row.Item("process_server") 

    if (-not ($Destination_Server)) {
        Write-Host "`r`n > Server: N/A...ensure CUBE << $CUBE_input >> exists in the table"
    } else { 
        Write-Host "`r`n` > Server $($i):" $Destination_Server[-1]
    }
}

$Destination_Server | Select-Object -Unique

Invoke-ASCmd -InputFile $JSON_file -Server $Destination_Server >$process_output
```

When I run it, it complains

```
Invoke-ASCmd : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String'
required by parameter 'Server'.

+ ... nvoke-ASCmd -InputFile $JSON_file -Server $Destination_Server >$proce ...
```

since `$Destination_Server` returns ONE unique value, why is it a problem for the Invoke command? It should simply accept one value as it has been passed.

Comment: You create an empty array object `$Destination_Server = @()` and then for each `$row` you add `$row.Item("process_server")` to it. So, there's scope for it contain more than one value. If it does only contain one value, `Invoke-ASCmd` expects a String object so you either need to iterate the values and/or convert it from an array to a string. `$Destination_Server | Select-Object -Unique` doesn't overwrite the value held in `$Destination_Server`, should this be `$Destination_Server = $Destination_Server | Select-Object -Unique` ?

Comment: Even `$Destination_Server | Select-Object -Unique` may produce an array, not necessarily a single string. Agreed, you need to look at iterating: `ForEach ($server in $Destination_servers) { <#do something with $server#> }`

Comment: @Jacob yes, you guys are right. That's what I need to do :)

Comment: @mjsqu I thought destination becomes a single string, but thanks for the hint :)